# Making Stylish inbox layout in android

Tags: android, database, listview, layout, android-fragments

I am trying to develop a chat application.

I have almost done this job. But the main problem is design of my inbox layout. I want to make my inbox conversation just like the Gmail inbox type i.e left side contains user pic along with the title and some message body and ride side having time and a check box. Anyone can help me with source code would be appreciated.
This is the layout i want.
[image: Inbox Layout]

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: i tried simple layout i.e it shows only text message like simple chatbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom listview for this.
Here are some links...
[Link 1](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html) [Link 2](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)